# System error 67 has occurred. The network name cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, iis, webdav

I have installed IIS server 10.0 on my PC with Windows 10. I made test webapplication for WebDav. Publish my app into folder and then add it into C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test. In IIS manager I created new site with name "test" and path with "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test". IP localhost and port 80. Its working fine. I setup WebDav modul for all users with read/write/delete permissions. Change Windows Authentication in Authentication module to true. And in Authorization Rules for All Users set to Allow. Then I tried in cmd "net use * http://localhost/" and get a message "System error 67 has occurred. The network name cannot be found."

Screenshot of settings of site in IIS manager:
[image: 1]
Screenshot of permissions of application folder:
[image: 2]
When I changed physical path of application to C:\inetpub\wwwroot its working. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: IIS Logs contain anything interesting (%SystemDrive%\Inetpub\Logs\Logfiles)?  Check the status codes in there.

Comment: No logs for my problem because I trying to create map network map from cmd. And my website working fine.

Comment: There still should be IIS log entries if it is hitting the IIS server.  After running your Net Use command, try typing netsh http flush logbuffer and recheck IIS logs.